# Subsetting Data Efficiently

Tags: r

I have a matrix of data:

```
x=matrix(rnorm(100))
```

This is a simple example with single column but assume there can be N different columns. My aim here is to get the most recent X days of data. Here X can be a vector or a single number. So for example if I want to get the most recent `c(10,20,30,40)`, this means I want the most recent 10,20,30,40 days of data.

My current code does it with a loop:

```
l = c(10,20,30,40)
mn.list<-list()
x=coredata(x)

for(j in 1:length(l)){
    hist1<-coredata(x[(nrow(x)-l[j]):(nrow(x)-1),]) #subset data
    if(is.null(dim(hist1))) dim(hist1) = c(len(hist1), 1)

    mn.list[[j]]<-hist1
}
```

so essentially, I am looping across each lookback and than getting the subset and then storing it in to a list which is something I need before I can do other data manipulations on it.

So my question is if there are better more efficient/elegant or multicore way of doing this to speed it up the most.

Comment: Is your data already sorted? Maybe chronologically in ascending order?

Comment: it financial data time series data and i am trying to construct a more efficient multi lookback function.

Comment: i am not trying to order anything thou, i just need to subset my data points...each subset according to the given lookback vector `l` and anchored to the last row or another most recent

Comment: Step 1: store it as a `data.table`.  Step 2: Store your indices in the list rather than the whole dataset.